# How to compare a part of an array item with a part of an array item from a second array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I have two arrays with files

```
arr1 = ['file1.webp', 'file2.webp', ...];
arr2 = ['file1.jpg', 'file2.png', 'file3.jpg', 'file4.jpg', ...];
```

how would I check which array items are equal, minus the `*.format` part?

The idea is that, if there are two equal items, a `webp` and an alternative source are available. While if an item has no match, no `webp` source was provided. Both cases would lead to different image handling later on.

I could compare the items inside two arrays like so: `let match = arr1.find( val => arr2.includes(val) );`

But this compares each entire item. I only want to compare the file names. The formats in which the files were provided need to be cut off, so I get:

```
arr1 = ['file1', 'file2', ...];
arr2 = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4', ...];
```

I can then filter out all matches between the two arrays. I've been searching for a solution for a real while, but I'm still not sure how to get there.

Comment: please add the wanted result form the first two arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a function that trims off the file extension, you can construct a Set of one of the transformed arrays. Then iterate over the other array and check whether its transformed item is in the Set or not:

```js
const arr1 = ['file1.webp', 'file2.webp'];
const arr2 = ['file1.jpg', 'file2.png', 'file3.jpg', 'file4.jpg'];

const transform = str => str.replace(/\.[^.]+$/, '');
const set1 = new Set(arr1.map(transform));
for (const item of arr2) {
  if (set1.has(transform(item))) {
    console.log('Match for', item);
  } else {
    console.log('No match for', item);
  }
}
```

Comment: I can only accept one answer and this what I went with. But I've experimented with all of the answers and they're all good with (in parts) slightly different results. So thanks everyone for helping me with this!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` with nested `some()`. To get the file name from complete name use `split('.')`and get the first element using `.split('.')[0]`

```js
let arr1 = ['file1.webp', 'file2.webp'];
let arr2 = ['file1.jpg', 'file2.png', 'file3.jpg', 'file4.jpg'];

let res = arr2.filter(a => arr1.some(b => a.split('.')[0] === b.split('.')[0]));
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could filter by looking to the right side.

```js
const getName = s => s.replace(/\.[^.]+$/, '');

var array1 = ['file1.webp', 'file2.webp'],
    array2 = ['file1.jpg', 'file2.png', 'file3.jpg', 'file4.jpg'],
    set1 = new Set(array1.map(getName)),
    common = array2.filter(s => set1.has(getName(s)));

console.log(common);
```

Answer (score 1):

write `extract` method to get value to compare. Just use the extract method in your code. Alternatively, you can build an `arr2Obj` to not to repeat the searches.

```js
const arr1 = ["file1.webp", "file2.webp"];
const arr2 = ["file1.jpg", "file2.png", "file3.jpg", "file4.jpg"];

const extract = item => item.split(".")[0];

let match = arr1.find(val => arr2.map(x => extract(x)).includes(extract(val)));

console.log(match);

// Alternatively, 
const arr2Obj = Object.assign({}, ...arr2.map(x => ({ [extract(x)]: 1 })));

const match2 = arr1.find(val => extract(val) in arr2Obj);

console.log(match2);
```